# How to restore variables to their initial state (when PowerShell loaded up)?

Tags: powershell

This  is something I have been wondering about lately. For example today I modified the `$env:path` in the current session and I wanted to restore it to how it initially was at PowerShell run time.

I could not figure it out, I eventually settled for:

```
 $Env:Path = [System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("Path","Machine")
```

But I wonder if there is a way to do this. I am thinking I can restore my own variables and objects by just running my profile `. $profile`, so this is just more specific to system variables and PowerShell variables.

Comment: The best way would be to Save `$Env:Path` when PowerShell starts. When PowerShell or your program is started, it will inherit the environment of the process from which it was staerted. That may not be the current registry settings. You could start another PowerShell console and get the environment variable value from there.